# How to return values from a populated array in a method to a ragged array in main

Tags: java, arrays, jagged-arrays

I have a main method that creates a ragged array with 3 rows and a random number of columns. The array is then passed to a class named Proj09Runner to populate the elements of the array with Integer count values from left to right and from top to bottom starting with 1 and ending with the sum of the sum of the lengths of the rows.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Date;
class Proj09{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    
    //Create a pseudo-random number generator
    Random generator = null;
    if(args.length != 0){
      generator = new Random(Long.parseLong(args[0]));
    }else{
      generator = new Random(new Date().getTime());
    };
    
    //Generate some small positive random numbers.
    int[] vals = {Math.abs((byte)generator.nextInt())%5+2,
                  Math.abs((byte)generator.nextInt())%5+2,
                  Math.abs((byte)generator.nextInt())%5+2};

    //Create an empty array object
    Object[][] array = new Object[3][];
    array[0] = new Object[vals[0]];
    array[1] = new Object[vals[1]];
    array[2] = new Object[vals[2]];

    //Instantiate an object from the student's code.
    Proj09Runner obj = new Proj09Runner();
    //Pass a reference to the empty array to the run method
    // of the object instantiated from the student's code
    // where the elements in the array object will be
    // populated with increasing Integer values.
    obj.run(array);

    //Display the data in the populated object.
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<vals[i];j++){
        System.out.print(((Object[])array[i])[j] + " ");
      }//end inner loop
      System.out.println();//new line
    }//end outer loop

    //Print some information that must descibe the
    // populated object.
    System.out.println();//blank line
    System.out.println("Row 0 width = " + vals[0]);
    System.out.println("Row 1 width = " + vals[1]);
    System.out.println("Row 2 width = " + vals[2]);
    System.out.println("Final value = " + (vals[0] + vals[1] + vals[2]));

    System.out.println("That's all folks.");

  }//end main
}//end class Proj09
//End program specifications.
```

I believe I have the right code to populate the array, I am just having issues returning the values to the main method in order to have the values printed out. Here is what I have so far.

```html
public Integer run(Object[][] array){
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
                array[i][j] = new Integer((i+1)*(j+1));
                return array;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `run` method is returning too early, after only setting the value of the first column of the the first row. It's also trying to return the `array`, which it doesn't need to.

Actually I don't see that it needs to return a value at all, as it's just populating the array with values. Changing the return type from `Integer` to `void` and removing the early `return` statement you get:

```
public void run(Object[][] array) {
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
            array[i][j] = new Integer((i+1)*(j+1));
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** If you need the array to be filled with consecutive values you could create a variable in the outer `for` loop, initialized to 1, and increment it in the inner `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0,k=1;i<array.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++,k++){
        array[i][j] = new Integer(k);
    }
}
```

Or if you want to keep your `for` loops simple you could do this too:

```
int val = 1;
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
        array[i][j] = new Integer(val);
        val += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! I have output. However, I believe that I am populating the array incorrectly. My first row increments by one, my second row increments by twos and the third by threes. The output that I need would have continuously incrementing numbers from row to row. If the first row ends with 5, the second row starts with 6 and so forth. Any ideas on how I can change my formula to get this output? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Take a look at the edited answer to see if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you so much for your help. It wasn't made super clear to me in my course that when you populate an array via a method, that I did not to return anything, this clears a lot of this up for me. Also I prefer the second for loop as it's a little easier to read and feels pretty simple to implement. Thank you!